# Get all of the low-level children of a node

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am struggling with the writing of a query for PostgreSQL. The table resembles a tree and every item can have *n* children.
I would like to get only and all the children of the lowest level(s) (which don't have any children by themselves) of a given element of the tree.

The structure:

```
CREATE TABLE items
(
    ikey integer NOT NULL,
    description character varying(255),
    parent integer,
    CONSTRAINT i_pk PRIMARY KEY (ikey),
    CONSTRAINT i_relation FOREIGN KEY (parent)
        REFERENCES items (ikey) MATCH SIMPLE
)
```

Some values of the table would look like this:

```
 1  "Products"  NULL --Parent
 2  "Metal" 1
 3  "Nails" 2
 4  "Chains"    2
 5  "Bicycle Chains"    4
 6  "Shimano Bicycle Chains"    5
 7  "Shimano Bicycle Chains"    5
 8  "7mm chain, black"    4
 9  "Wood"  1
 10 "Cutting Boards"    8
 11 "Cutting Board Holder" 8
```

Most of the solutions on SO deal with not very deep trees which have just 1-2 levels. Or it is known from which parent the children are required.

I would like to select all children of "Chains" (4), which would give the following result:

```
6   "Shimano Bicycle Chains"    5
7   "Shimano Bicycle Chains"    5
8   "7mm chain, black"    4
```

To be honest, recursive queries are not my strongest skill. I had the idea already to search upside down - getting all items first which are never used as parents and then going down, but this only shifts the problem to the point again that I have to go down recursively from the given parent which seems a bit over the top.

Comment: I don't understand if you want all the children, or just leaf children. It seems "10 - Cutting Board" should be included but it's not in your list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all children items of an item in all levels you can write a recursive CTE. For example:

```
with recursive
n as (
  select * from items where parent = 4 -- Children of "Chains"
 union all
  select i.*
  from n
  join items i on i.parent = n.ikey
)
select * from n
```

Result:

```
 ikey  description               parent 
 ----- ------------------------- ------ 
 5     Bicycle Chains            4      
 8     7mm Chain Black           4      
 6     Shimano Bicycle Chains 1  5      
 7     Shimano Bicycle Chains 2  5
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vzfeacRjvec5tLdgL2BVBJ/1).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a recursive query. Instead, you can simply select the rows with `ikey`s that do not occur as parents:

```
select i1.* from items i join items i1 on i.ikey = i1.parent where i.parent = 4 and 
    not exists (select 1 from items i2 where i2.parent = i1.ikey)
```

Comment: After running it over and over through my dataset it appears to me this would just return the next lower level of partent which doesn't have any children

Answer (score 0):

Another recursive CTE, with extras.
The base key that started the recursion & level of the tree.

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE RCTE_OFFSPRING AS (
>   SELECT ikey as base, 0 as lvl
>   , ikey, description, parent
>   FROM items
>   WHERE ikey = 4
>   
>   UNION ALL
>   
>   SELECT cte.base, cte.lvl + 1
>   , itm.ikey, itm.description, itm.parent
>   FROM items itm
>   JOIN RCTE_OFFSPRING cte 
>     ON cte.ikey = itm.parent
> )
> SELECT * 
> FROM RCTE_OFFSPRING
> WHERE lvl > 0
> ORDER BY base, lvl, ikey
> ```

| base | lvl | ikey | description | parent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 5 | Bicycle Chains | 4 |
| 4 | 1 | 8 | 7mm chain, black | 4 |
| 4 | 2 | 6 | Shimano Bicycle Chains | 5 |
| 4 | 2 | 7 | Shimano Bicycle Chains | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=956761d19c0224915099f59cbfd62998)*